# How to start Firefox with a empty page via terminal under Linux, despite default page configured in FF

Tags: linux, firefox, terminal

How to start Firefox with a empty page via terminal under Linux, despite default page configured in FF

Envirement:

- Linux
- Terminal
- Firefox

What I have found is the follow for use on terminal:

Open new firefox with in browser configured default startpage:

```
firefox
```

Open new firefox with one webpage:

```
firefox --new-window https://stackoverflow.com
```

How to start Firefox with a empty page via terminal under Linux, despite default page configured in FF. I dont looking for, how to open a new blank Tab of FF by Terminal.

It can be, a blank page have a adress too, a I didn find like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "URL" of empty page in Firefox is `about:blank`. You just need to execute

```sh
firefox about:blank
```

Analogous, to open new window with blank page:

```sh
firefox --new-window about:blank
```